# Split by delimiter and concatenate string problem

Tags: shell-script

I am very new with linux shell commands. I need to read a text file which contains several lines as '!Platform_series_id = GSE1145'. I should split each line to use '**GSE1145**' after the '=' sign part of it. Finally I want to produce a link such as 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE5nnn/**GSE1145**/suppl/**GSE1145**_RAW.tar'
The bold parts of the link will be taken from the txt file. The remaining parts are constant. This was the story.

If I come to the point where I got stuck:

When I run the following code

```
while read p; do
  A="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<$p)"
  echo "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE5nnn/$A/suppl/$A_RAW.tar"
done < a.txt
```

It gives an unexpected result

/suppl/.tarcbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE5nnn/ GSE1145
/suppl/.tarcbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE5nnn/ GSE1643

Then I tried simply concatenating the same variable

```
while read p; do
  A="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<$p)"
  echo "$A$A"
done < a.txt
```

But still the answer is not what I expect. It just behaves as it is written echo $A.

GSE1145
 GSE1643

To understand the problem, finally I tried the following code:

```
A="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<< '!Platform_series_id = GSE1145')"
echo $A$A
```

It gives me a correct result

GSE1145 GSE1145

So what is the problem when I read it?

By the way, when I try following code, It works! But why? I think this is not the correct way. If I put spaces as many as the length of the $A,

```
while read p; do
  A="$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<$p)"
  echo "        $A$A"
done < a.txt
```

GSE1145 GSE1145
 GSE1643 GSE1643

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Does your text file have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings by any chance? Regardless, I'd suggest using a text-processing utility such as `awk` for this kind of task - rather than a shell loop.

Comment: It doesn't give you the correct result... When you `cut` the string the result has a leading space. It's always there, you just don't see it... Try `echo X$A` and you'll see the space... Anyway, as suggested, this isn't a job for `while..read` (which should never be used to process text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should split each line to use 'GSE1145' after the '=' sign

That's a signal to use **awk**(1).  Its basic idea is to read lines and split them automatically, and let you do what you will.  To make awk print your link,

```
awk -F ' += +' \
    '{ printf "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov" \
              "/geo/series/GSE5nnn/%s/suppl/%s_RAW.tar", $2, $2 }' filename
```

That will print *something* for each line in the file.  awk lets you choose which lines to process how, either by line number or by matching a regular expression.

awk is worth learning.  Treat it nicely and it'll be your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two questions with your suggestion. I have tried it. The last line of the txt file is "!Platform_series_id = GSE2478". First, it processed the last line only. Why? Second, it printed out: "_RAW.tarSE2478ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE5nnn/GSE2478
". It looks like a little bit mixed up.

Comment: @ykpemre please see my comment about DOS line endings on your original post - you can check using `cat -et a.txt`for example

Comment: @steeldriver I checked. It printed this. M-oM-;M-?!Platform_series_id = GSE1145^M$
!Platform_series_id = GSE1643^M$
!Platform_series_id = GSE2109^M$
I dont know what are these characters "M-oM-;M-?" and "^M".

Comment: @ykpemre the `^M` characters at the ends of the lines indeed confirm that it is DOS formatted. The `M-oM-;M-?` at the beginning is probably a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: @ykpemre, you're splitting on the regular expression that is the argument to `-F`.  If the pattern isn't present on the line, it won't split, and $2 is empty.  Printing it won't look like much, but you should get a blank line for every such input.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden Thanks. Then the problem is to transfer the file from Windows. So can you suggest any solution for this case?